# What is the difference between the 'sound' and 'audio' tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there a technical or functional difference between the [sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sound) and [audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/audio) tags?

Comment: Anyone know if these be merged automatically, or does someone need to weed through them manually?

Comment: To answer my own question, yes. Just learned about "Tag Synonyms" http://askubuntu.com/tags/synonyms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking through the questions tagged with either sound or audio it appears there are being used to indicate an identical concept.

The sound tag is used almost twice as often as audio (32 vs 17; 28 vs 13 excluding the questions tagged with both terms) and therefore it should probably be the primary tag with audio being the synonym.